# AS3 BitmapData and .as files

Tags: actionscript-3

i have .fla and .as files.
.fla:

```
import test ;
var b:test = new test();


var myBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(150, 150, true, 0x80FF3300);
var test:BitmapData = new BitmapData(150, 150, false, 0xFF0000); 
var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(test); 
addChild(myImage);
```

and .as

```
package 

{
    import flash.display.*;

public dynamic class test extends flash.display.BitmapData
{
    public function test(arg1:int=621, arg2:int=427)
    {
        super(arg1, arg2);
        return;
    }
}
```

}

But its not working, BitmapData must have the same name like loading .as (test.as), but i don't know how do that :|

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do? By the way, if you want to create instance form test class, why do you create BitmapData instead?

Comment: Other .swf is loading "test" from test.as, test.as is loading BitmapData named "test"

Comment: without import test ;
var b:test = new test();
"test.as" isn't loading into .fla file.

Comment: Look at this part: 
var myBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(150, 150, true, 0x80FF3300);
var test:BitmapData = new BitmapData(150, 150, false, 0xFF0000); 
var myImage:Bitmap = new Bitmap(test); 
addChild(myImage);

You are just creating empty bitmap, assign empty BitmaData to it and put the empty bitmap to stage. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If you will not add some functionality on top of the BitmapData why bother creating another class and extend the BitmapBata Class you can just use it directly.

as i understand you are not seeing anything on the screen, well this is normal because you're adding a blank bitmap to the stage ie: its BitmapData has nothing to deliver.

Maybe you need to link the Test class to an image imported into your fla so you'll get something to see on the screen.

Comment: But how to link? I want empty BitmapData